# Python: make an off-center polar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, polar-coordinates

I have a list of (r, theta) values and know how to make a polar plot. Is there some way to take this plot and shift it off-center? My goal is to have one copy shifted left and one copy shifted right and to graph an overlap.

Comment: Matplotlib docs include an example: https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/polar_demo.html   If you can provide some test data to your question...

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you somehow illustrate what you want a bit more precise?